# Get applied sales rule ids for quote in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, quote

I want to retrieve all salesrule ids applied to the quote, by using my quote id

for example:

```
$quote = $this->quote->create()->loadActive($quoteId);
$salesruleIds = $quote->getSalesRuleIds(); // how ??
$discounts = array();
foreach($salesruleIds as $salesruleId){
  $rule = $this->salesRule->load($salesruleId);
  $discount['name'] = $rule->getName();
  $discount['description'] = $rule->getDescription();
  $discount['discount_amount'] = $rule->getDiscountAmount();
  $discounts[] = $discount;
}
return $discounts;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$salesruleIds = explode(',', $quote->getAppliedRuleIds());
```

If you want the only salesrule, you can try the following way.

```
$this->coupon->loadByCode($quote->getCouponCode());
$salesruleIds[] = $coupon->getRuleId();
```

Where coupon is the instance of **Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon**

Comment: it gives me empty result, but the sales rule is applied to the order

Comment: Check your quote object. This is working code. Also, check to quote table coupon_code column.

Comment: turns out i need to `$quote->collectTotals()` first after load my quote